# No method found for class java.lang.String in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, json-deserialization

I have producer and consumer configuration

Producer

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, BeltEventDescription> kafkaBeltEventDescriptionTemplate(final ProducerFactory<String, BeltEventDescription> producerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
}
```

with config properties

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, BeltEventDescription> producerBeltEventDescriptionFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(Map.of(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class
    ));
}
```

Consumer

```
@Bean
public KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaStringConsumer() {
    return new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerFactory(beltGroupId).getConfigurationProperties());
}
```

with config props

```
private ConsumerFactory<String, BeltEvent> consumerFactory(final String groupId) {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(Map.of(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
            ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId,
            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class,
            ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class,
            ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000,
            ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 10000,
            ConsumerConfig.GROUP_INSTANCE_ID_CONFIG, ("SchedulerCoordinator-" + UUID.randomUUID()))
    );
}
```

but when I try sending message or listening, I don't know what fails exactly, I get the message

> Listener failed
> No method found for class java.lang.String

What's wrong?